# Odoo V9 Product template issue

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to make some simple modification on "products.template".

Here after is .py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class myproducts_example(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    _columns = {
        'price' : fields.float('PPH', digits=(6,4)),
        'example_id': fields.many2one('product.template', 'DCI'),
    }
```

and also my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_form_inherit">
    <field name="name">product.template.form.myinherit</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="standard_price" position="replace">
            <field name="sample" placeholder="e.g sample" />
        </field>             
        <field name="invoice_policy" position="replace"/>          
     </field> 
  </record>
```

Everything works well, no error while installing the module, but when I try to update the module I have this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/thinkmal/mcom-tests-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
   execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/thinkmal/mcom-tests-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/service/server.py", line 245, in app
return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/http.py", line 1488, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/http.py", line 1462, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/thinkmal/mcom-tests-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/http.py", line 1637, in dispatch
ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/http.py", line 360, in registry
return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 354, in get
update_module)
  File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 385, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
   File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 334, in load_modules
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
   File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
   File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 132, in load_module_graph
models = registry.load(cr, package)
   File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 168, in load
model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
   File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/models.py", line 592, in _build_model
original_module = pool[name]._original_module if name in parents else cls._module
   File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 84, in __getitem__
return self.models[model_name]
  KeyError: 'product.template'
```

I didn't really understand the error.

I've tried to delete the module and reinstall it. Same behavior: Works first and the same message error after.

I've also tried to delete Database and restart from beginning, when I click on Inventory: I have this message error.

```
 File "/home/thinkmal/Desktop/odoo-9.0c-20160117/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 640, in read_combined
  view_arch = etree.fromstring(view['arch'].encode('utf-8'))
 File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3092, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:70473)
 File "parser.pxi", line 1828, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106307)
 File "parser.pxi", line 1716, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105098)
 File "parser.pxi", line 1086, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:99780)
 File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94254)
 File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:95690)
 File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94757)
 XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: i line 186 and li, line 186, column 277
```

Iam completely lost! Please help! :P

Comment: Do you have `'depends': ['base']` in your `__openerp__.py` file?

Comment: yes I do have  'depends': ['base'].

Comment: You need to set `product` in depends not base, 'depends': ['product'], because `product.product_template_only_form_view` is available in product module not in base module. So product.template module is not found simply update depends.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer. it seems to work, but I still have the same message error each time I click on ''Inventory".
Besides, I'm trying to hide "invoice_policy" field and I have a message error:<field name="invoice_policy"> can't be localized in parent view.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: because invoice_policy isnt from product module, check of what module is it from

Comment: @dccdany : You can find "invoice_policy" on Debug Menu -> View Fields..
Did I miss somehting..?

Comment: Go to: Configuration > Database Structure > Models. Search for product.template model. There, search for your field and click on it, in the right of the wizard, it will say which module add this field. Thats the module that you should add in the dependence